# Como capturo el nombre de un Botón al darle clic utilizando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

mi siguiente problema es que Quiero capturar el nombre de un botón al darle clic, pero no he encontrado la forma de como hacerlo con JS, para unos puede ser muy fácil pero estoy apenas aprendiendo y no se como hacerlo, ya que me gustaría capturarlo con JavaScript

ejemplifico

Tengo un botón con el nombre Enviar, yo al darle clic quiero capturar ese nombre que tiene(Enviar) con JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El evento onClick puede recibir como parámetro una [interface `MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) que, entre otras cosas tiene un [elemento `target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) que es una referencia al elemento que ha originado el evento.

Así, puedes asignar el mismo manejador de evento a varios botones y, a través de este elemento, averiguar el ID o el texto del botón que lo lanzó, solo por poner un ejemplo.

```html
<button id="boton1">botón 1</button>
<button id="boton2">botón 2</button>
<button id="boton3">botón 3</button>
<button id="boton4">botón 4</button>
<button id="boton5">botón 5</button>
<button id="boton6">botón 6</button>
<script>
function botonOnClick(e) {
  console.log("id: " + e.target.id);
  console.log("texto: " + e.target.innerHTML);
}

let botones = document.querySelectorAll('button');
botones.forEach((boton) => {
  boton.addEventListener('click', botonOnClick);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, era lo que andaba buscando :)